# cannot identify xdg-open behaviour for console application

Tags: command-line, 20.04, xdg-open

I have created file association for a console application which accepts inputs from stdin and gives output at the stdout. It works normally when I run the application from the terminal using ./myExe. But when I launch the exe using xdg-open 'myFile', it gives out the stdout on the terminal but it does not accept any input from the stdin (It takes input from the /dev/null).

I m not able to identify whether this is the standard behaviour or have I missed something.
And If this is the standard behaviour why is stdout available then?
I m using Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Note : Both stdin and stdout are available when I use xdg-open through a ssh session.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior.

- In an interactive terminal, standard input and output are attached to the terminal: standard input is by default the keyboard, standard output and standard error is the terminal output on screen.
- A program running in a terminal session in the background will display output to the screen, but will not accept input from the keyboard. The program you launch with the `xdg-open` command runs as a separate thread in the system, independent from the terminal session, just as if you would have launched the application from clicking a file in the file manager. Once the application is launched, `xdg-open` terminates and your terminal is released for further input from your side. If you issue the command `bg`, you will indeed see there are no background processes in your terminal.
- A program/process started from a graphical desktop environment (i.e. after clicking an icon in a menu, after launching a file, after entering a command in the Run dialog) is not connected to a terminal, so neither input or output can be seen.

Standard input/output can be redirected to a file or another device.